# unexpected token comma in my JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var param = {'alternate',$(this).closest('.myId').attr('id'),$(this).siblings('input').val().trim(),'',''};
```

What's wrong here? I see nothing wrong but I gotten an error saying unexpected , in this line.

Comment: The `object` syntax is incorrect. I think you want `array`

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: @Tushar of course I know that, but where?

Comment: Did you want to build an array ? If so use square brackets: `var param = [...];`

Comment: You really think array is made by `{}`? Because it's not. Use `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `{}` with `[]` in order to make this an array.

```
var param = ['alternate',$(this).closest('.myId').attr('id'),$(this).siblings('input').val().trim(),'',''];
```

[JS - LINT1](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) or [JS - LINT2](http://www.jslint.com/) to validate your java script code.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the definition of a javascript object and an array. You probably want to create an array, do this:

```
var param = ['alternate',$(this).closest('.myId').attr('id'),$(this).siblings('input').val().trim(),'',''];
```

Or to be a bit readable:

```
var param = [
  'alternate',
  $(this).closest('.myId').attr('id'),
  $(this).siblings('input').val().trim(),
  '',
  ''
];
```

For context objects are defined as `{key: value}`:

```
var param = {
   foo: 1,
   bar: 2
}
```